# Highchart: Line chart zoom not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts, linechart

I am having problems with zoom in Highchart's Line chart in IE8. Zoom is not working with the chart integrated in our application.

Zoom works fine in IE8 with demo samples. But the same stand alone code is not working, if I use it in our application.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Demo code used:

```
   $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            resetZoomButton: {
                theme: {
                    visibility : 'hidden'
                }
            },
            backgroundColor: null
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (�C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '�C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
```

Thanks,
Sarath

Comment: Not sure whether it will help, but one more observation on debuging  highchart code is that the Window.Event's Offset.X and Offset.Y doesnt seem to return the correct values.

Comment: Maybe you are using old version of Highcharts? Don't you have any errors in js console?

Comment: We are using highchart version 4.0.3 (took it from the top of js file Highcharts JS v4.0.3 (2014-07-03)). Regarding JS errors I do not see any in the console.

Comment: Actual version is 4.0.4, but 4.0.3 should work too. Anyway, could you create some demo page with that issue? Maybe you have just some DIV which overlays chart?

Comment: I will not be able to create a demo page, our website is an output of quiet a few custom scripts and JS frameworks. What I can do is give you the link to our dev website, if you can provide me your email Id.

Comment: You can contact with our [support](http://www.highcharts.com/support) via email directly.